# How would one use Kotlin's reflection?

Tags: ubuntu, kotlin, reflection

I feel like I don't fully understand the depth of some deeps.

```sh
$ cat blya.kt 
inline fun<reified T> omg() {
    val x = T::class.supertypes  // such an innocent init
}

fun main() {
    omg<Int>()
}

$ kotlinc -d omg.jar -include-runtime blya.kt && java -jar omg.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
blya.kt:2:6: warning: variable 'x' is never used
    val x = T::class.supertypes
     ^
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:84)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getSupertypes(ClassReference.kt:42)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt:9)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt)

$ ls /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar  -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2893798 Sep 10 13:15 /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar

$ # hmm, strage it's not found on default, well, ok, let's add it

$ kotlinc -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/ -d omg.jar -include-runtime blya.kt && java -jar omg.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
blya.kt:2:6: warning: variable 'x' is never used
    val x = T::class.supertypes
     ^
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:84)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getSupertypes(ClassReference.kt:42)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt:9)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt)

$ kotlinc -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar -d omg.jar -include-runtime blya.kt && java -jar omg.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
blya.kt:2:6: warning: variable 'x' is never used
    val x = T::class.supertypes
     ^
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:84)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getSupertypes(ClassReference.kt:42)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt:9)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt)

$ kotlinc -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar -d omg.jar -include-runtime blya.kt && java -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib -jar omg.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
blya.kt:2:6: warning: variable 'x' is never used
    val x = T::class.supertypes
     ^
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.error(ClassReference.kt:84)
    at kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference.getSupertypes(ClassReference.kt:42)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt:9)
    at BlyaKt.main(blya.kt)
```

As if I shouldn't want to use it at all.

And even with verbose output it pretends to be including it ... up to some extent.

```sh
$ kotlinc -verbose -d omg.jar -include-runtime blya.kt
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
logging: using Kotlin home directory /snap/kotlin/53
logging: configuring the compilation environment
logging: configure scripting: Added template org.jetbrains.kotlin.mainKts.MainKtsScript from [/snap/kotlin/53/lib/kotlin-main-kts.jar, /snap/kotlin/53/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar, /snap/kotlin/53/lib/kotlin-script-runtime.jar, /snap/kotlin/53/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar]
logging: loading modules: [java.se, jdk.accessibility, jdk.attach, jdk.compiler, jdk.dynalink, jdk.httpserver, jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.jartool, jdk.javadoc, jdk.jconsole, jdk.jdi, jdk.jfr, jdk.jshell, jdk.jsobject, jdk.management, jdk.management.jfr, jdk.net, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.scripting.nashorn, jdk.sctp, jdk.security.auth, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.unsupported, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.xml.dom, java.base, java.compiler, java.datatransfer, java.desktop, java.xml, java.instrument, java.logging, java.management, java.management.rmi, java.rmi, java.naming, java.net.http, java.prefs, java.scripting, java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl, java.sql, java.transaction.xa, java.sql.rowset, java.xml.crypto, jdk.internal.jvmstat, jdk.management.agent, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.internal.ed, jdk.internal.le, jdk.internal.opt]
```

Can anyone give some hint on what's happening?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I believe that: a) Kotlin doesn't pick up the reflection jar by default, as most projects won't need it (and presumably they don't want to encourage it); you need to include it explicitly.  b) When specifying the classpath, you need to specify `.jar` files directly; it'll find `.class` files within a named dir, but not `.jar` files.  And c) you need the reflection jar at runtime, i.e. in the classpath for `java`, not just for `kotlinc`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I include it explicitly?

Comment: Something like `… && java -classpath /snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/snap/kotlin/current/lib -jar omg.jar`?

Comment: Thanks but still the same.

Comment: It turned out a bit more complicated.

Comment: Please tell — by adding your own answer, if possible.  It will help anyone else who hits this problem in future (as well as satisfying my curiosity).

Comment: @gidds sure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a day worth of brief googling discovered that:

1. As we all know Kotlin does not include reflect implementation into the jar produced, and that is not "by default", that is "at all", i.e. "in no way".
2. In the meantime `java -jar omg.jar` makes java automatically ignore *every* classpath setting, save for, maybe, those specified on the manifest (which I wasn't able to make work) <sub>because ... well, that's why</sub>.

The real pipeline to build and run should actually read

```sh
kotlinc -d omg.jar -include-runtime omg.kt
java -cp omg.jar:/snap/kotlin/current/lib/* OmgKt
```

where `OmgKt` is the main executable class name you should guess. In simple cases, like this one, it obviously derives from the source filename, and it probably can be found if you unzip, and look at the contents of, the jar file... somehow it didn't work at start when I first tried it.

(And `/snap/kotlin/current` denotes a typical kotlin installation path.)